# Bootstrap how to show data from row in modal window

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Want to show modal window in the center of webbrowser and show user information from my bootstrap td row which user clicked. Can you help me out? Below find my current code. I can't find the way

Here below you see i made tr as modal and put data-id to 1:

```
....
<tbody>
   @For Each item In Model.Transports
        Dim currentItem = item
           @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal">

 <td class="col-lg-4 text-center vert-align_td">@item.Name</td>
 <td class="col-lg-4 text-center vert-align_td">@item.Surname</td>
 <td class="col-lg-4 text-center vert-align_td">@item.Age</td>
....
```

Heres my modal window where i want to put all information:

```
@<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>

        Information for lp number: 

        Name: 
        Surname:
        Age: 

    </div>
    <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
    <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my JS:

```
 $(function () {
        $('#orderModal').modal({
            keyboard: true,
            backdrop: "static",
            show: false,

        }).on('show', function () {
            var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('Lp');
            //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
            $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for LP: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
        });
    });
```

**EDITED (for further duscussions:)**

...

```
@For Each item In Model.Transports
   Dim currentItem = item
     @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="12">
        <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Lp</td>
        <td class="col-lg-1">@item.Name</td>
```

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        //var getIdFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
        // if you wnat to take the text of the first cell 
        var getIdFromRow1 = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:first-child').text();
        var getIdFromRow2 = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:second-child').text();
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for LP: ' + getIdFromRow1 + '</b>'))
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for DataPrzyjazdu: ' + getIdFromRow2 + '</b>'))
    });
```

**EDIT2:**

```
 $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var getIdFromRow1 = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:first-child').text();
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for Lp: ' + getIdFromRow1 + '</b>'))

        var getIdFromRow2 = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for Data przyjazdu: ' + getIdFromRow2 + '</b>'))
    });
```

Modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

table:

```
 @<tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="12">


    <td class="col-lg-1 text-center vert-align_td">@item.Lp</td>
<td class="col-lg-1 text-center vert-align_td">@item.DataPrzyjazdu</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with your code:

1. You should use `show.bs.modal` event instead of `show` event. [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-events).
2. You should use `$(event.relatedTarget)` (return the `tr`) instead of `$(event.target)` (return the `modal`).

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    //var getIdFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
    // if you wnat to take the text of the first cell 
    var getIdFromRow = $(event.relatedTarget).find('td:first-child').text();
    $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Information for LP: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
        <th>Col 4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="12">
        <td>ID is 12</td>
        <td>Col 2</td>
        <td>Col 3</td>
        <td>Col 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: youu took data from tr and how to take values from td's items? Note i have razor and data from for each loop

Comment: `values from td's items` what do you mean by `values`? I was updated my answer to take the text in the first `td` in the row.

Comment: see my main topic : EDIT clause - that's to what i changed what is there wrong?

Comment: `what is there wrong` - 1. You have 2 rows `$(this).find('#orderDetails')`. The second row override the first. 2.  The second row attempt to insert `getIdFromRow2` value to the modal. To get `getIdFromRow2` you used the selector `td:second-child`. This selector is not legal. The right selector is [`td:nth-child(2)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: please check inside main post (EDIT2)- i placed current code and screenshoot what i get when i click no matter which row i see nothing in modal window... and i would like to see e.g Lp, DataPrzyjazdu etc..

Comment: Any errors in the `console`? Also, see the first point in my previous comment `1. You have 2 rows $(this).find('#orderDetails'). The second row override the first`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98094/discussion-between-johndoe-and-mosh-feu).